# Как получить два различных дефолтных представление коллекции

Tags: c#, wpf

Стоит следующая задача: нужно в два различных листбокса вывести подмножества элементов листа, полученные путем применения двух различных фильтров. Для получения представления я использую метод CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView, однако он всегда возвращает одну и ту же ссылку. Из-за этого я не могу задать для этих представлений разные фильтры. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Конкретно читайте мой ответ, строка `= new CollectionViewSource...`, кол-во `ICollectionView` как я думаю вы поняли, может быть любое и с любым фильтром.

Comment: При использовании этой строчки в листбокс вообще ничего не выводится

Comment: Ну значит не так используете. Вот набросал допустим простой [пример](https://pastebin.com/V7pw7BFt), в XAML два `ListBox` (`{Binding MaleCollection}` и `{Binding FemaleCollection}` соответсвенно), в итоге получаем [такое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x93p.png), где 1 коллекция раскидана по фильтру на два `ListBox` по гендеру.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @EvgeniyZ такое можно и ответом оформить, хороший и полезный для SO пример.